# How to implement t-SNE in a model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I split my data to train/test.
When i use PCA It is straight forward.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA()
X_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)
```

From here i can use X_train_pca and X_test_pca in the next step and so on..

But when i use t-SNE

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
X_train_tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0).fit_transform(X_train)
```

I can't seem to transform the test set so that i can use the t-SNE data for the next step e.g. SVM.

Any help?

Comment: t-SNE is non-parametric, are no parameters to be learned from the training set, so there is no transform method.

Comment: PCA is non-parametric either. This must not have anything to do with the availability of a transform method for the TSNE class implementation

Answer (score 7):

I believe that what you're trying to do is impossible.

t-SNE makes a projection that tries to keep pairwise distances between the samples that you fit. So you cannot use a t-SNE model to predict a projection on new data without doing a refit.

On the other hand, I would not give the output of a t-SNE as input to a classifier. Mainly because t-SNE is highly non linear and somewhat random and you can get very different outputs depending with different runs and different values of perplexity.

See [this](https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/) explanation of t-SNE.

However, if you really with to use t-SNE for this purpose, you'll have to fit your t-SNE model on the whole data, and once it is fitted you make your train and test splits.

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

size_train = X_train.shape[0]
X = np.vstack((X_train,X_test))

X_tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0).fit_transform( X ) 
X_train_tsne = X_tsne[0:size_train,:]
X_test_tsne  = X_tsne[size_train:,:]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. 
I thought the recommendation is to use dimentionality reduction after train/test splitting, which is why i didnt know how to do it! Theory wise, i thought that t-SNE use in this manner should be possible. Anyway, thank you again, I'll work on it!

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation [TSNE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) is a tool to **visualize** high-dimensional data. A bit lower in the description we can find: *it is highly recommended to use another dimensionality reduction method (e.g. PCA for dense data or TruncatedSVD for sparse data) to reduce the number of dimensions*.

My suggestion would be use *TSNE* for visualisation and *PCA* or *TruncatedSVD* as a part of the machine learning model.

Comment: Thank you! I already used PCA, but thought that t-SNE might give me a different answer because it is using probability distribution..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to train or find components of train data and reduce test data by using the train data components, you should use like:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
pca = PCA()
X_train_pca = pca.fit(X_train)
X_test_pca = np.dot(X_test, pca.components_.T)
```